# New Blender 2.8 Subdivision Surface UV Smooth isnt working

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

UV Smooth option isnt working for me in new blender.
I checked "Smooth,keep corners"
My mesh does not have creased edges
[image]

Comment: This is just a changed feature. Smooth, keep corners behaves exactly as expected.If you want the old behavior back, you'll have to try asking the devs, there could be a Smooth Corners feature, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in order to make it work now  you have to get rid of ngon
[image]

[image]